# Unable to pass this react test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a form to which when I enter any amount less that 4000 or greater than 100000 should show a validation message. This works perfectly fine when but when I run my test case, it keeps failing and I don't know why. But the same test case passes if I use hard coded values in place of Number(minLoanAmount) (eg: Number(enteredLoanAmount < 4000). Can someone please help me.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInputHelperCurrency } from '@honeycomb-npm/honeycomb-react';
import { ErrorMessage } from '@honeycomb-npm/honeycomb-react';
import { getStaticContent } from '../utils';
import './loanAmount.scss';

type LoanAmountProps = {
    label: string;
    errorMessage: string;
    minLoanAmount: string;
    maxLoanAmount: string;
};

    const LoanAmount: React.VFC<LoanAmountProps> = (loanAmountProps) => {
        const { label, errorMessage, minLoanAmount, maxLoanAmount } = loanAmountProps;
        const min = parseFloat(String(getStaticContent(minLoanAmount)));
        const max = parseFloat(String(getStaticContent(maxLoanAmount)));
        const [enteredLoanAmount, setEnteredLoanAmount] = useState<string>();
        const handleAmountChange = (name: string, value: string) => {
            setEnteredLoanAmount(value);
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="loan-amount">
                <TextInputHelperCurrency
                    data-testid="textInputHelperCurrency"
                    id="loanAmount"
                    label={String(getStaticContent(label))}
                    value={String(enteredLoanAmount)}
                    onChange={handleAmountChange}
                />
                {Number(enteredLoanAmount) < Number(minLoanAmount) ||
                Number(enteredLoanAmount) > Number((maxLoanAmount)) ? (
                    <p data-testid="checkId">Invalid</p>
                ) : null}
            </div>
        );
    };

export default LoanAmount;
```

My test case:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import LoanAmount from './LoanAmount';
 
describe("LoanAmount", () => {

  it('should not show validation message upon passing a valid amount to the input field', () => {
    render(<LoanAmount label={''} errorMessage={''} minLoanAmount={''} maxLoanAmount={''} />);
 
    const inputEl = screen.getByTestId("textInputHelperCurrency");
    userEvent.type(inputEl, "5000");
 
    expect(screen.getByTestId("textInputHelperCurrency")).toHaveValue("5000");
    expect(screen.getByTestId("textInputHelperCurrency")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByTestId("checkId")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

The error says: expected document not to contain element, found <p data-testid="checkId">Invalid</p> instead
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that as you're rendering the component with **minLoan** and **maxLoan** props set to a value of 0 (`minLoanAmount={''} maxLoanAmount={''}`), both `Number(minLoanAmount)` and `Number(maxLoanAmount)` will be 0.

Your condition `5000 > 0 || 5000 < 0` is then `true`, and the `<p>` is shown.